# How can use "poetry run fix" as "poetry run black src/" in pyproject.toml in poetry?

Tags: python-3.x, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I have used Poetry as Python package management for my Python library.
As we know there are some tool formater like black.
I want to run `poetry run fix` which acts as `poetry run black src/`.
Based on doing search on the internet I have found I have to set `tool.poetry.scripts` on pyproject.toml but when I run `poetry install` I have got below errors:

"not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

pyproject.toml is like the below code:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "test-utils"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Person"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8.1"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
black = "^23.11.0"
flake8 = "^6.1.0"
flake8-pyproject = "^1.2.3"
isort = "^5.12.0"
mypy = "^1.6.1"
pytest = "^7.4.3"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
test-utils = "test_utils.__main__:cli"
fix = "black src/"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "jfrog-source"
url = "https://jfrog.example.co/artifactory/api/pypi/all-pypi/simple"
priority = "primary"

[tool.flake8]
per-file-ignores = [
    "__init__.py:F401",
]
inline-quotes = "double"
eradicate-whitelist-extend = "isort.*"
max-line-length = 120
count = true

[tool.mypy]
namespace_packages = true
explicit_package_bases = true

exclude = "venv/|env/|virtualenv/|docs/|build/"
mypy_path = "src/"

[tool.black]
preview = true
line_length = 88

[tool.isort]
profile = "black"
line_length = 88
```